# C++ variadic templates deduction logic

Tags: templates, g++, c++17, variadic

I have simple code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<class... Types>
class A;

template<>
class A<> {
public:
    explicit A() {
        std::cout << "empty" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class Head, class... Tail>
class A<Head, Tail...> {
public:
    explicit A(Head head, Tail ...tail) : tail_(tail...) {
        std::cout << head << std::endl;
    }

private:
    A<Tail...> tail_;
};


int main() {
    auto a = A(1, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile:

```sh
test2.cpp:27:20: error: class template argument deduction failed:
     auto a = A(1, 2);
                    ^
test2.cpp:27: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

It could be fixed by adding deduction guide like:

```cpp
template<class... T>
A(T...) -> A<T...>;
```

My question is why compiler can't resolve such simple case?

Comment: Perhaps the deduction is broken by template specialization? Looking up the constructor requires knowing which template specialization is to be used, which in this case requires looking at the constructor

Comment: Lots of similar questions, most just say "bug": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430921/deduction-guides-and-variadic-class-templates-with-variadic-template-constructor . Deducing from static factory function arguments seems to work well, so I'd recommend that as a workaround.

Comment: Be carefull, here the standard is pretty important. I don't see `c++17` as tag of this question.

Comment: The recursiveness isn't crucial, btw; I can reproduce the issue if the only specializations are <> and <class T>

Answer (score 3):

Implicit deduction guides are only generated from the constructors of the *primary* class template. (C++17 [over.match.class.deduct]/1.1) You have not defined the primary class template.

Therefore, the class template partial specialization `template<class Head, class... Tail> class A<Head, Tail...> ...` is ignored when performing class template argument deduction. Writing an explicit deduction guide is a possible solution to this problem, as you have observed.

Comment: Thank you for answer!
So another way to fix it - specify constructor to the primary class template?

Comment: @forward32 Yes, you could do that. But I think that defining the primary class template, when it is never going to be instantiated, is bad style. The explicit deduction guide would communicate intent better.